# Why did Loki kill this character?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

If he really wants to be a king of Asgard he could easily prove himself to his father that he is more powerful than Thor

> instead of killing Odin.

It shows that he has no humanity for his father.

Comment: I edited your question to hide spoilers. I'm not really sure what you meant by "no humanity for his father" though. Grammar aside, Loki has intense disdain for humans and wouldn't want to show anything resembling "humanity".

Comment: I don't understand the line, "It shows he has no humanity for his father." Please explain?

Comment: Loki isn't a human who needs to show off humanity...

Comment: I think instead of "humanity", maybe the word "empathy" or "compassion"?

Comment: First off, the movies been out over a year so anyone here on this thread shouldn't be worried on spoilers....There is nothing to say that has happened. You only think it has... It's entirely feasible that Loki and Odin are working together on this... Odin would be week and need to Odinsleep before Thanos arrives... but to do so shows weakness and guarantees the attack... unless Loki is there "as Odin"... that'd be the irony... Loki gets to be king but not as himself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Loki killed* Odin for numerous reasons.

- Odin had told him that he would never be king.
- In Loki's eyes, Odin stole his birthright from him by taking him from Laufey - preventing him from ever being king again.
- Odin had banished Loki to the dungeons, after being left for dead (after falling from the bridge to the Bifrost).

Loki is consumed by jealousy and anger, largely stemming from a lack of approval by Odin and jealousy of Thor.

Thor is a hero. Loki is a disgraced criminal who has been defeated twice.

Having been defeated by Thor twice already, killing Odin is the only other way to claim the throne.

<sub>*as we learned later, Loki did not kill Odin, he kidnapped him and hid/stranded him on Earth.</sub>

Comment: Its not clear that Loki really killed Odin...

Comment: @SachinShekhar, Yes, that's why I put the asterisk and the note that there is no proof that Odin is actually dead.

Answer (score 11):

Despite what we see at the end of Thor: The Dark World,

> Odin is not dead. Loki lacks the raw power and the chutzpah to take out Odin, All-Father, and Ruler of Asgard.

More than likely this is another deception by Loki to rid himself of the burden of his step-brother, Thor while cementing his rule on the throne.

Loki has about half of the attributes necessary for being a good king. Unfortunately for Odin, Thor only has half as well. I suspect Odin would prefer Thor to rule, not necessarily purely from Thor being of his bloodline, but because when all is said and done, Thor is necessary for Ragnarok not to be a complete rout of the Asgardians. Left to Loki's rule, Thor would not survive until then. Without Thor, Ragnarok is lost, no Asgardians survive and a new age of gods (and men) does not happen.

Odin knows this because he sacrificed his eye at the Well of Mimir and has done everything in his power to ensure Thor's will be leading the Asgardians at this final day.

- What most people don't know about Odin is he embodies the powers and spiritual essence of his other brothers, Vili and Ve, and that power is known to Asgardians as the Odin-power or Odin-Force.
- Not only does this mean Odin is far more powerful than the averages Asgardian, his abilities have few equals in the Nine Realms. Loki, while one of the most powerful sorcerers in Asgard, is not an equal of Odin in any way.
- Upon Odin's passing (as it has happened on more than one occasion in the canon comic series) this power will pass to the strongest descendent of Odin. That would be Thor.
- Since that has not happened yet, and Loki being aware of magic, is probably cognizant of this, the last thing he would want is for the Odin-power to find its way to Thor until he can claim it for himself.

Knowing Loki, he has imprisoned Odin somewhere away from his tools (Gungnir, Spear of Heaven) and somehow blocked Odin's access to his own prodigious magical abilities. It will likely fall to Thor, as it has so often in the comics, to rescue his father from Loki's innovative and dangerous prison.

What Loki often fails to remember is, any place strong enough to imprison Odin, is certainly strong enough to keep Loki locked away until a week before Ragnarok...

Comment: Yeah, there's no way that Odin is dead. It'd be entirely obvious to all of Asgard if that happened. It's not the kind of thing you'd be able to hide. Most likely Loki has tricked his father into entering the Odinsleep, which is how he recharges the Odin-force, in the comics.

Comment: @MarkBessey - After he's recharged his Odin-force, does he go Odin-Super-Saiyan?